# MDX/SSRS - how do you get the “ALL” label to display in a report then add additional dimensions

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2008-r2

I recently posted a question on how to get the ALL label to appear in a SSRS report. "whytheq" was kind enough to post an example that works. Below is the MDX with an added dimension that if I uncomment it will give me an error:

***Query (8, 5) Two sets specified in the  function have different dimensionality.***

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD] AS 
    [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All] 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Freight]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      //[Product].[Color].[Color].MEMBERS*
      [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD],
      [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS

    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works Cube];
```

I get that I have a Dimension at the .MEMBERS level and I've also added the .[YTD] dimension.

I did noted that if I comment out the .[YTD] and uncomment the [Product] dimension this works but I have to use an * instead of a comma like so.

```
      [Product].[Color].[Color].MEMBERS*
      //[Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD],
      [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS
```

Is it possible to have the Product dimension include in the rows along with the YTD and Calendar Month.MEMEBERS?

Comment: Highly recommend you read this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216769(v=sql.80).aspx until you grok the differences between a tuple, a member, and a set, and which one of those each part of your MDX query is generating.

Comment: Hey, in addition to my answer, I just wanted to correct you a bit: to get the All member to show up in addition to the members of a hierarchy, simply pull the members of the hierarchy's root level itself, rather than attribute level. So `[Due Date].[Calendar Month].Members` rather than `[Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Greg's answer to your question is fine, I just wanted to show you the nuts and bolts of your query so maybe you get a better understanding of how you use an MDX query and a cube's structure to produce the result you want.

First, here's the basic structure of most MDX queries:

```
    SELECT 
      Set_Expression ON COLUMNS
     ,
        Set_Expression ON ROWS
    FROM CUBE;
```

(There's a bit more to MDX, but this is probably 80-90%.)

A *set expression* is an expression that returns a set - so as you can see it's pretty important that understand what a set is and how to build a *valid* expression that returns the *right* set.

So first, what is a set, again? A *set* is -drum roll- .... a **set** of tuples<sup>1</sup>. But not just any tuples - ***only tuples which have the same dimensional hierarchical structure*** (also called *dimensionality*). Let's look at some examples of potential set expressions, and I'll tell you if they're valid or not.

A set with one tuple? **VALID**.

```
{ Product.Product.Laptop }
```

A set with two tuples from the same dimension hierarchy? **VALID**.

```
{ Product.Product.Laptop , Product.Product.Desktop }
```

A set with two tuples from the same dimension hierarchy but different levels? **VALID**.

```
{ Date.DateHierarchy.Year.2008 , Date.DateHierarchy.Quarter.2009Q1 }
```

A set with two tuples from the same dimension, but a different hierarchy? **INVALID**.

```
{ Product.Product.[Laptop] , Product.Category.[Hardware] }
```

Why is this invalid? Because the two tuples have different dimensionalities. If you consider back to the literal metaphor of a "cube", each dimension hierarchy is a "face" and each tuple is a slice of the cube along the faces that make up its dimensionality (and any dimension hierarchy that isn't part of the tuple's explicit dimensionality is treated as an implicit "All members" at execution time) So in order to combine two or more tuples into a set - so you can extract them from the cube in a single slice - they must all come from the same set of faces - the same dimensionality.

A set with a tuple and a *set function* (an MDX function which returns a set of tuples) from the same dimensional hierarchy? **VALID**.

```
{ 
  Tail ( Order ( Product.Product.Members, Measures.Profit, BASC ), 5), 
  Product.Product.All 
}
```

A set with two set functions from the same dimensional hierarchy? **VALID**

```
{   Subset(Product.Product.Members,0,5), Subset(Product.Product,Members,6,5) }
```

A set with a tuple with two dimensions? **VALID** *but!* you have to put parentheses around the tuple. (You can put parentheses around tuples with just one dimension, but it's not necessary.)

```
{ ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2015 ) }
```

A set with two tuples each with two dimensions at the same respective hiearchical levels? **VALID**

```
{ 
  ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2015 ),
  ( Product.Product.Tablet, Date.Year.2013 ) 
}
```

(Note the members don't have to be the same at all, just the hierarchies. Hopefully this is the point where you recognize what "dimensionality" means.)

A set with two tuples each with two dimensions at the same respective hiearchical levels but not in the same order within the tuples? **INVALID**

```
{ 
      ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2015 ),
      ( Date.Year.2013, Product.Product.Tablet ) 
    }
```

(Compare to UNION in SQL - you have to have consistent ordering so MDX can build the set up to perform other tasks, such as nesting each member of a tuple correctly on a query axis.)

And finally, if we want to combine two sets from *different* dimensional hierarchies into a single set, we use the handy dandy **CrossJoin** function:

```
CrossJoin ( { Product.Product.Laptop } , Date.Year.Members )
```

As you've discovered, you can also use an asterisk **(*)** to perform a cross join  of two sets

```
Product.Product.Laptop * Date.Year.Members
```

Now it's important to understand what's going on here. I said "combine sets" earlier, but as you've seen with all the examples, you can't just throw various sets of tuples with different dimensionality together into a single set.

So what's a CrossJoin doing?

Well, given a CrossJoin of

```
 {Set With Tuple Dimensionality (A)} * {Set with Tuple Dimensionality (B)}
```

The resulting set has a tuple dimensionality of `(A, B)`.

So looking back at our CrossJoin example, our left-hand side has just one tuple, and its dimensionality is `(Product.Product)`. And our right-hand side has many tuples (every member of the `Date.Year` hierarchy) with the dimensionality of `(Date.Year)`. So our final set of tuples will have the dimensionality of `(Product.Product, Date.Year)`.

So say we had every year from 2010-2015 in our cube, our final set would be 6 tuples of

```
{ 
  ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2010),
  ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2011),
  ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2012),
  ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2013),
  ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2014),
  ( Product.Product.Laptop, Date.Year.2015)
}
```

So you could in theory tack on more tuples to this set as long as they're simpatico with the same dimensionality - say, `(Product.Product.Tablet, Date.Year.2013)`

So this would also be a **VALID** set expression:

```
{ 
 Product.Product.Laptop * Date.Year.Members, 
(Product.Product.Tablet, Date.Year.2013)`
}
```

So now going back to your problem, if we uncomment your broken line of code we see you've got

```
{
  [Product].[Color].[Color].MEMBERS *
  [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD],
  [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS
}
```

So, here you've got a set of tuples

```
[Product].[Color].[Color].MEMBERS *
      [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD]
```

whose tuples have the dimensionality of

```
(Product.Color, Due Date.Calendar Month)
```

And then you're trying to tack on another set of tuples to this set

```
[Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS
```

whose tuples have a dimensionality of

```
(Due Date.Calendar Month)
```

Now do you understand the error message you got?

And this leads me to why I wrote this very long post at 1 in the morning: **your error is an error of fundamentally misunderstanding the concept of a set in MDX, not simply an error of syntax.**

Obviously you want your final set's tuple's dimensional hierarchy structure to be

```
(Product.Color, Due Date.Calendar Month)
```

And again, Greg's answer achieves this. So really I hope my post has explained *how* Greg's answer achieves this!

Also, here's two alternate syntactical ways to achieve the same set result you want on the COLUMNS axis:

```
NON EMPTY { ([Product].[Color].[Color].Members, [Due Date].[Calendar Month].Members ) }
```

and

```
NONEMPTY ( [Product].[Color].[Color].Members, [Due Date].[Calendar Month].Members )
```

Basically, the `(set, set)` syntax also performs a crossjoin, as does the `NONEMPTY(set1, set2)` function. Just so you can see that there are multiple syntactical ways to achieve the same concept.

---

1. Quick refresher on tuples: Each cell in your cube represents a unique set of dimension hierarchy members. A *tuple* is a set of dimension hierarchy members which constitute a set of cells (or *coordinate space*) in your cube. (*N.B.*: Any dimension hierarchy not explicitly named in a tuple expression uses its *default member*, which if not explicitly set in an SSAS cube model is the **All** member.)

So the tuple expression `(Product.Product.Laptop)` points to the cellset in the cube where the member of the `Product.Product` dimension hierarchy is `Product.Product.Laptop`, and for all the other dimension hierarchies the member is the default member (if it's the All member, the cube basically doesn't do any work, since no slicing is required on that dimension hierarchy.)

In the image below, you can see how the tuple expression `(Time.[2nd half], Source.nonground.air)` is applied to the cube to produce its coordinate space.

[image]

Okay, back to the top.

Comment: Nice explanation -  I have to ask : is this a joke "There's a bit more to MDX, but this is probably 80-90%" ? I think that the way in which a simple `mdx` script, like your initial snippet, looks like a `sql` script is 80-90% of the problem!

Comment: @whytheq Less of a joke than a hand-wavy bit. MDX like SQL is so much more about conceptualization than syntax.

Comment: Also, I wish somebody had written something like this for me back when I was learning MDX - I kept thinking I could just syntax my way to the correct query!

Comment: You're correct Kyle - it is really important to understand the fundamental basics of mdx to use as the building blocks for more complicated scripts. [MDX vs SQL] is like [Chess vs Chequers] ....

Comment: Fantastic answer. Upvoted. Struggling MDX slingers everywhere appreciate your time @KyleHale

Comment: You should write a book :)

Comment: Greatly appreciate the time you took Kyle to answer this. Like you said I have been trying to syntax my way out but I now see why I was going down the wrong path. This will be very useful to many new comers to MDX. I have copied this post into my reference folder of MDX files. Using your comments I was also able to bring in other dimensional hierarchies, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Product].[Color].[Color].MEMBERS*
      {
       [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All].[YTD],
       [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS
      }

    } ON ROWS
```